# In a TFS build definition, can a variable be defined in terms of another variable?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, environment-variables, build-process

I have a working MSBuild file with certain targets that I want to run in a TFS build. The targets rely on certain environment variables and MSBuild properties being already defined. I have a "Variables" tab in my TFS build definition editor where I can ostensibly set the values of variables so that they are indeed defined when the targets run, but it seems that only literal values are allowed - if I want to define a variable in terms of another variable (eg `%OTHER_VARIABLE%\subfolder`), there is no variable expansion happening. I've tried various ways of specifying the other variable (eg `$(OTHER_VARIABLE)`) but the value is always seen literally by MSBuild.

Is there a way to define a variable in terms of another variable?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML build or vNext build? Could you specify which function do you want to achieve by using the variable?

Comment: We're evaluating TFS 2015. We're pretty new to TFS so I'm not sure what you mean by XAML build or vNext build. Right now we're comparing TFS vs our existing TeamCity build configurations, where we define "build templates" that contain all of the requirements for a build, including environment variables, and we rely quite heavily there on being able to define variables in terms of other variables - those other variables mostly being defined by TeamCity itself (eg. the agent work directory).

Comment: I think we're going to be able to achieve what we need by adding new targets to our MSBuild file that set up the environment first (only TFS builds would need to use these), but I was curious about whether this would be possible in the build definition itself. Having briefly experimented with an earlier version of TFS in a former life (2010?), it seems to me that TFS 2015 build configurations have taken some concepts from TeamCity, in fact (eg. the various kinds of "build steps" that can be added to a build definition), but TC still seems much more sophisticated.

Comment: Mmm. A new target won't work for us because our build invokes other build projects using the <MSBuild> task, and environment variables set in an outer task don't flow through to inner tasks. Vexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using TFS 2015, You can use this extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks

https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-variable-tasks/wiki/Expand-Variable

```
When you define a variable in the Variables screen and use other variables as value, they won't be expanded (as you may have expected). Instead the literal text is passed to the tasks in the workflow. Without this little task the following configuration won't work:

Variable    Value
Build.DropLocation  \\share\drops\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)

By adding the Expand variable(s) task to the top of your workflow, it will take care of the expansion, so any task below it will receive the value you're after.
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this natively in TFS, but I guess this is it for now.